GNU Radio Companion Link to Python Library/Folder?
I have installed GNU Radio Companion on MacOS using HomeBrew
I am running it, but its giving me errors that I need to install MATPLOTLIB for some blocks.
I already have MATPLOTLIB and several other packages installed.
How do I link GNU Radio to to these? I see no options in the GnuRadio Companion to set the default python folder.
I have searched online, tutorials but not able to find an answer.
Expecting GNURadio to use a default python folder but what does it use? I looked around for different options and google searches.

if GNU Radio Companion or anything else says it can't find the matplotlib module, that module is not installed into the same python prefix; that's an unambiguous diagnostic right there :)
So, use the same homebrew method to install your matplotlib.
